# Android TV Remote Control API

Tags: android, android-tv, television

Is There any API to Control Android TV Using TCP/IP?
ex: I want change the channel of tv or change the sound volume
or open specific apps by its package name?

Comment: See https://support.google.com/androidtv/answer/6122465?hl=en